# I want to get user-input in a same line, but print() function sends focus on next line insted of focussing on same line

Tags: dart

Here is my simple dart code. That takes user-name.

```
import 'dart:io';
void main() {
    print("Enter Your name: ");
    String userName = stdin.readLineSync();
    print("Welcome $userName");
}
```

here is output:

```
Enter Your name:  // I want to enter it here.
jay    //but it forces me to enter here.
Welcome jay
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`stdout.write` should do what you want:

```
stdout.write("Enter Your name: ");
```